# How to apply transformation to all methods in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I want to apply the following transformation to all responses...  I can do it one by one, but I have dozens.. so there must be a way to do it globally? I tried injecting it, but I get all sort of errors.

```
transformResponse: function (data) {
    var wrappedResult = angular.fromJson(data);
    return wrappedResult.records;
}
```

I am assuming is wrapping it here.. but I can't figure it out how.

```
bme.factory('envelopInterceptor', [function () {
    return {

    };
}]);
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this piece of code and [its source](http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html) (The author gives an example to parse dates)

```
myApp.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function(responseData){
        transformYourResponse(responseData);
        return responseData;
    });
}]);
```